# Example of using CURRENT_DATE in JPA query

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Can anyone point me to an example on how to use `CURRENT_DATE` in a JPA query?

`CURRENT_DATE` is specified in JPA but I haven't been able to make it work. I always get the `unexpected token [CURRENT_DATE]` exception. Since it is specified in JPA all providers should comply with it right?

I'm using EclipseLink 2.0 BTW.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It can be used like so:

```
Query query = manager
    .createQuery("SELECT c FROM CITIES c WHERE c.founded = CURRENT_DATE");
for (Object city : query.getResultList()) {
  System.out.println(city);
}
```

...where *founded* is a temporal type:

```
  @Column(name = "FOUNDED")
  @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
  private Date founded = new Date();
```

*Not a great example, but you get the idea. I'm using Eclipselink 1.1.2*

Comment: You're really close. I got that far just before seeing your reply. I'm trying to do something like

Select x from Table x where x.id=1 and (x.lastModified-CURRENT_DATE)>=365

I need to use calculation on dates.

Comment: Is it possible to do datetime arithmetic using JPA? You'd have to have some function to turn the difference into days (and not minutes or months or millennia, etc.). I am not aware of any such functions. Do the date arithmetic in Java and then just select comparing against the resultant range.

Comment: I guess this is a flaw or missing functionality of JPA. I'll have to do it that way I guess. Thanks!

Comment: @McDowell - How we can implement the logic for CURRENT_DATE - 1, this doesn't works

Answer (score 5):

The answer to this question was retrieving the values via JPA and then do the math in plain Java.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the [Expression Framework](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_EclipseLink_Expressions_(ELUG)) there is the `Expression currentDateDate()` method on the `Expression` (`org.eclipse.persistence.expressions.Expression`) object.

Comment: I'll need to try it but I was really trying to avoid using generic JPA queries to avoid dependance on the persistence provider.