# Create Query matching for current date

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Example of using CURRENT_DATE in JPA query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637323/example-of-using-current-date-in-jpa-query)

I am trying to add a query to my repository to compare a date stored in the db against the current date.

My query is like this:

```
@Query("Select c from Customer c where c.terminated != 1 or c.terminationDate > <currentDate>")
public List<Customer> getTerminatedCustomers();
```

What can I insert for `<currentDate>`?

If everything fails I could add a parameter to the method and pass the current date to the query like this. But I would prefer a more elegant solution, if possible.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This question is actually a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637323/example-of-using-current-date-in-jpa-query). According to the Java Persistence API specification section 4.6.17.2.3 there are predefined functions `CURRENT_DATE`, `CURRENT_TIME` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. So the query would have to be defined as

```
 select c from Customer c where c.terminated != 1 or c.terminationDate > CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: Regarding the fact that `CURRENT_DATE` is a standard JPA function and it should work the same way across all JPA providers and RDBMS, it should be `CURRENT_DATE()` when used in Hibernate with SQL Server. ([proof](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15298426/1429387))