# Hibernate JPQL CURRENT_DATE not working on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have the following JPQL query:

```
SELECT x FROM Bla x WHERE x.deadline < CURRENT_DATE
```

This works as expected on MySQL. But SQL Server complains that `CURRENT_DATE` is not recognized.

I am asking myself what exactly the problem is. Then `CURRENT_DATE` is a standard JPA function that should resolve independent from the underlying RDBMS.

Further the Hibernate documentation also has `CURRENT_DATE` documented (see here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#ql-expressions).

I googled and found a lot fo comments telling me that I shall use `CURRENT_DATE()` instead. But this isn't JPQL.

So why is `CURRENT_DATE` not working and what is the solution?

I am using Hibernate 4.1.8.Final.

Best regards,
Florian

Comment: 8 year later, still not work .

Answer (score 2):

You can try to pass current date as a parameter to the query. Also, there will no portability issue whith this.

```
session.createQuery("SELECT x FROM TABLE_NAME x WHERE x.deadline < :currentDate")
        .setParameter( "currentDate", currentDate)
        .list();
```

Else, you can try query with `current_date()` instead of `current_date`, which is part of HQL expression.

Comment: That would be a solution but does not explain why Hibernate ignores the JPA standard here for MSSQL.

Answer (score 0):

try using `GETDATE()`

```
SELECT x FROM Bla x WHERE x.deadline < GETDATE()
```

Comment: But GETDATE() is not JPA standard? Does that also work on other databases (especially mysql)?