# JPQL (spring jpa) CURRENT_DATE not giving the right time

Tags: spring, jpa, jpql

I am trying to use the `CURRENT_DATE`[1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/kodo41/full/html/ejb3_overview_query.html) variable inside a jpql select (spring jpa hibernate) like this:

```
@Query("select f from FutureEventEntity f where f.executionTime > CURRENT_DATE")
List<FutureEventEntity> findFutureEvents();
```

It is also mentioned here[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475680/create-query-matching-for-current-date) and here[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637323/example-of-using-current-date-in-jpa-query).
Unfortunately it does not work. It always findes all Entities regardless of the time. But when I give him the time from java, it works fine:

```
@Query("select f from FutureEventEntity f where f.executionTime > :now")
List<FutureEventEntity> findFutureEvents(@Param("now") Date date);
default List<FutureEventEntity> findFutureEvents(){
    return this.findFutureEvents(new Date());
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this maybe the wrong way in order to use the current date and time inside a jpql without giving it as a parameter?
(of course my little `default` method can ship around this problem, but i am curious what a better way there could be in order to improve myself.)

Also some information to the database:
I am using a MySQL Database for test purposes. When I use the command `SELECT NOW(),CURDATE(),CURTIME()` directly inside the console, it returns me the correct data.

Comment: What is the current time on server on which your database is hosted? What does query `select CURRENT_DATE` returns

Comment: I am using a MySQL Database for test purposes. When I use the command `SELECT NOW(),CURDATE(),CURTIME()` directly inside the console, it returns me the correct data.

Comment: Have you tried the SQL query directly in console.

Comment: From what I read, the `CURRENT_DATE` is replaced by jpa, so it is not the same `CURRENT_DATE` I can insert to the Database console directly. The interesting part is, that I can replace it with `NOW()`, but this now is a MySQL Function. So when I one time change my database, I am not sure if this will still work. So I was wondering, what the correct JPQL Funktion for the Date and Time is...

Comment: In that case can you enable "showSql" and check in your IDE console to what value CURRENT_DATE is replaced by JPA

Comment: I enabled the `showSql` and `format_sql` in order to get a nice debug and yes, that helped ...Because now I see that the `CURRENT_DATE` does NOT get replaced by JPA. It gets passed as a MySQL Function and only returns the Date, not the Time. And so the Time is set to 00:00:00.0000 and this is always before my events, based on the same day. So Now I am searching again for the JPA native function for Date **and** time...

Comment: naja, I also doubted that JPA replace CURRENT_DATE

Comment: CURRENT_DATE in MySQL is a synonym for CURDATE. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date  and you can easily see what your JPA provider is invoking in the datastore (as you've already been asked).